# How to display only the day and month of a date based on the locale?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I would like to display only the day and the month of a date, but I want it based on the user's locale.

For example I have the following date: `21/05/2015 00:16:00 GMT+10`

I want to have `May 21` if the locale is `en_US` or `21 May` if the locale if `fr_FR`for example.

I looked with the `dateStyle` of `NSDateFormatter` formatter but couldn't find what I want.

Comment: Use an actual format string with the formatter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
let d = // the date
let df = NSDateFormatter()
let format = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate(
    "dMMMM", options:0, locale:NSLocale.currentLocale())
df.dateFormat = format
let s = df.stringFromDate(d)
```

Note that both language and region settings on the device are involved in the outcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know `dateFormatFromTemplate`. Will be useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple extension for it:

```
public extension NSDate {
func getNiceDate() -> String! {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let format = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate(
        "dMMMM", options:0, locale:NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US"))
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format

    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
}
```

}